# prevent resize parent behind child

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, resize

do resize `targ` from bottom to top
when `targins` is reached I want to force - stop resizing
current code allows child to be visually outside of parent and that's what I need to prevent
Any help?

```js
$(function(){
 $('#targ, #targins').resizable({
  handles: 's'
 });
 $('#targins').draggable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'parent'
 });
});
```

```css
.targ{
 width:45%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#ddd;
 height:79px;
}

.targins{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 display:grid;
 align-items:center;
 background:gold;
  text-align:center;
  top:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class='targ' id='targ'>
<div class='targins' id='targins'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this property to your `targ` class: `overflow: hidden;`.